# isEventSupported.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I've seen this question several times but isn't the same file. 
I'm building an electron app on macOS with React and using webpack to transpile. 
When I run it, there is an error in the console.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function isEventSupported.js:17`

here's the code in the file:

```
'use strict';

var ExecutionEnvironment = require('fbjs/lib/ExecutionEnvironment');

var useHasFeature;
if (ExecutionEnvironment.canUseDOM) {
  useHasFeature = document.implementation && document.implementation.hasFeature &&
  // always returns true in newer browsers as per the standard.
  // @see http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-domimplementation-hasfeature
  document.implementation.hasFeature('', '') !== true;
}
```

line 17 is the line that starts with `usehasFeature` but I don't know what his error means.

Comment: Care to share more code? I'm betting you have some exporting issues.

Comment: More than happy but it's a pretty big app already. Any ideas where i should be looking? Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Check your exports, make sure they are being correctly exported so that when you `require`, you get what you expect.

Comment: Make sure you dont have two `export default` in your App. Also how does your react component look like

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Just checked and I don't have any duplicate export default. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @AndrewLi Going to check. Thanks.

Comment: @denislexic I came across one more thing , you should not be doing `class extends React.createClass` instead of `class extends React.Component {}`

Comment: try to update React dependities (react-dom), it helps me